# Difficulty in choosing the best event after selecting a date

Tags: jquery

I have a textbox in which I have the DateUIPicket attached and I need to do do an AJAX post after selecting the date. My problem here is if I use a Click event it's not able to read the new date chosen. What is the best event to use such that it's able to read the new date chosen and post the date.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you mean the jQuery UI Datepicker.

If so, you cannot rely on built-in events since the textbox is populated programmatically. The Datepicker widget provides a `onSelect` callback function for you to use, but you can only set it on creation:

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        // Send Ajax POST using dateText as data
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input").change(function()...
```

That event will fire as soon as a new date is chosen. See http://api.jquery.com/change/ for reference.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `onClose` event of the `datepicker`

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onClose